# Path lifting theorem. Correctness of the proof.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-verification

Let $p:X\to B$ be a covering and $g:I\to B$ be a path on $B$ with $p(x_0)=g(0)=b_0$. Then there exists unique lifting path $f:I\to X$ s.t. $g=pf$ and $f(0)=x_0$. I didn't get fully the proof from the book, so I've tried to prove it by myself, but I'm not sure about its correctness.

Proof:
Since $p$ is a covering, any point in $Y$ has an "appropriate" neighborhood. So does the points of the set $g(I)$. Since $g(I)$ is compact we can choose finite subcover $V_1$, $V_2$...$V_n$ of such neighborhoods. Suppose $b\in V_1$. Then there exists $U_1\subset p^{-1}(V_1)$ s.t. $U_1$ is homeomorphic to $V_1$. Suppose $V_1\cap g(I)=N_1$. Thus we can construct the part of $f$ by sending its points to inverse of $N_1$ according to homeomorphism from $U_1$ to $V_1$. Continuing this algorithm on $U_2$...$U_n$ we can find all values of $f$ uniquely.

I know that my proof has some holes, and I think I know how to fix them. But I'm wondering whether is the idea itself correct or not.

Comment: The key point you're missing is an organized way to continue the path, it's not clear how your inverses patch together. The idea seems basically correct, though.